# I want to display my text after my thumbnail slider div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I want to display my text after my thumbnail slider div something like this,
my active slider class: "`itm0 selected`"
my thumbnail id: "thumbs"
i want to display text below my #thumbs div automatically when it is active
i tried this CSS, but not worked,

```
.itm0 .selected{
    #thumbs::after{
         content:"first active image";
    }
}

.itm2 .selected{            
    #thumbs::after{
         content:"second active image";
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <img class="itm0 selected"></img>
  <img class="itm1"></img>
</div>
```

when 2nd img active in slider

```
<div id="thumbs">
   <img class="itm0"></img>
   <img class="itm1 selected"></img>
</div>
```

etc.

anyone have some solution?
or how can I do it in javascript?
I am new newbie.. give some idea friends

Comment: can you put some html??

Comment: when 1st img active in slider
<div id="thumbs">
<img class="itm0 selected"></img>
<img class="itm1"></img>
</div>
when 2nd img active in slider
<div id="thumbs">
<img class="itm0"></img>
<img class="itm1 selected"></img>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to using jQuery, you can do the following.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79fryyz1/

**HTML**

I've added an additional div under the #thumbs div. I've given it a class called `caption`. This will be used to show the text under the div. Then, I've added a data attribute called `data-caption` to store the text to be displayed after each image. I've also added a toggle button for demonstration purposes.

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <img class="itm0 selected" src="http://bit.ly/1S6znnc" data-caption="first active image"/>
    <img class="itm1" src="http://bit.ly/1MKyvBI" data-caption="second active image"/>
</div>
<div class="caption">first active image</div>
<a href="#" class="toggleBtn">Toggle</a>
```

**JS**

When the image slider is changed, and a new image is selected, you can pick up the caption from the data attribute and display it under the `#thumbs` div.

```
$('.toggleBtn').click(function() {
    $('img').toggleClass('selected');

    var caption = $('img.selected').data('caption');
    $('.caption').html(caption);
});
```

Comment: thanks karanmhatre. I have some idea now.
shall you please add how the sliders moves automatically instead of toggle?

Comment: i want to do the slider design same as that in http://www.studiopress.com  for the hover of my slide, testimonial appear to be left and name in botttom as in the (http://www.studiopress.com), how can i do it?

Comment: You can use the same logic to achieve what you need. You can use the setInterval function in javascript to automatically move the slider. Please ask specific questions. I cannot explain how the complete thing is built from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange way of doing it, but here's how it could work...

```css
.thumbs { 
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  background:green;
}

.thumbs:after {
  content: ' ';
  position:absolute;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:5px;margin:100px 0 0;
}

.thumbs:nth-child(1):hover:after {
   content:"first thumb";
}

.thumbs:nth-child(2):hover:after {
   content:"second thumb";
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbs"></div>
<div class="thumbs"></div>
```

Comment: thanks james.
But how can i do it inside .itm0 .selected class??
if i want to say clearly,
i want to display my text after the slider thumbnail "thumb" div, when the slider thumbnail image is active.

Am i clear?